# Get users which I have friends in common

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 sql tables:

1) "users" with the following structure and data:

user_id, user_name

```
 1, John
 2, Mike
 3, Chris
 4, Paul
 5, Kelly
 6, Kevin
```

2) "userfriends" which cotains friendship relations, with the following structure and data:

userfriends_user_id, userfriends_friend_id

```
 1, 2 => [ John is friend with Mike ]
 2, 3 => [ Mike is friend with Chris]
 2, 4 => [ Mike is friend with Paul ]
 5, 1 => [ Kelly is friend with John]
 6, 5 => [ Kevin is friend with Kelly]
```

I want to make a SELECT (user_name, user_id) to get those users where John have common friends with, so the output should be Chris, Paul, Kevin. Can this be done in only ONE select statement ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "common friends". Typically, if you wanted friends in common, then you would pick any 2 users, and take the union of their friends.

Comment: Your question is unclear "where John have common friends with". Chris and Paul are friends with Mike, but Kevin isn't friends with either of them... Can you explain how you are determining the expected output?

Comment: Ok, fist of all sorry for my english. In this example John has 2 friends Mike and Kelly. I wanted to output users that are friends with my friends(Mike and Kelly). So John and Chris has common friend => Mike, John and Paul has common friend Mike, John and Kevin has common friend => Kelly. The output should be Chris, Paul and Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't know if I am thinking too complicated right now. Here is what I've come up with:

```
select * from users
where user_id in
(
  select user1_id
  from
  ( -- users except John and their friends (again except John)
    select userfriends_user_id as user1_id, userfriends_friend_id as user2_id 
    from userfriends where userfriends_user_id != 1 and userfriends_friend_id != 1
    union 
    select userfriends_friend_id as user1_id, userfriends_user_id as user2_id 
    from userfriends where userfriends_user_id != 1 and userfriends_friend_id != 1
  ) others
  where user2_id in
  ( -- friends of John's
    select userfriends_user_id from userfriends where userfriends_friend_id = 1
    union
    select userfriends_friend_id from userfriends where userfriends_user_id = 1
  )
);
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/338d87/1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by getting all the friends of your friends.  This requires a join from the `userfriends` table back to itself.

Then, just look at the the "friends of friends" that appear more than once.  You can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
select uff.userfriends_friend_id
from userfriends uf join
     userfriends uff
     on uf.userfriends_friend_id = uff.userfriends_user_id
where uf.userfriends_user_id = 1
group by uff.userfriends_friend_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

TEST this query:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_id IN
(
    SELECT uf.userfriends_friend_id AS CommonId
    FROM userfriends uf, 
        (
            SELECT uf2.userfriends_friend_id
            FROM userfriends uf2
            WHERE uf2.userfriends_user_id = 1
        ) A
    WHERE uf.userfriends_user_id = A.userfriends_friend_id

    UNION

    SELECT uf.userfriends_user_id  AS CommonId
    FROM userfriends uf, 
        (
            SELECT uf2.userfriends_user_id
            FROM userfriends uf2
            WHERE uf2.userfriends_friend_id = 1
        ) A
    WHERE uf.userfriends_friend_id = A.userfriends_user_id
)
```

I tested SQLfiddle provided by @Thorsten Kettner. It works. Output is correct. Thanks @Thorsten Kettner!

Comment: Great ! This is the best example so far, but with over 2500 users this select statement is low, but I'm guessing there is not other way. Thanks a lot for your help guys !